# How to restore an oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am very new to Oracle and customer gave us their oracle database files.

ARC00016_0724940467.001
initVISUAL.ora
VISUAL.2010-07-22-1637.log
VISUAL-trace.sql
SYSAUX01.DBF
SYSTEM01.DBF
UNDOTBS01.DBF
USERS01.DBF

I am running Oracle personal edition. I want to create a new database using the above files and connect to it using ODBC and VB.NET.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You won't get there from here.

Either make sure that your version, edition and operating system are the same as the client. If so, you may get away with doing a restore from a physical copy of the data files (DBF) and control files.

If not, you are best off asking for a database export (either old-fashioned exp, or preferably a datapump export). That is a 'logical' copy of the tables/data etc and it is much easier to pull that into a different environment.

Comment: +1, although it is conceivable there's enough here to recreate the database, assuming identical environments and versions and that all of the dbf files are present.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file came from the same OS, and that VISUAL-trace.sql is a backup of controlfile to trace. 
 copy the initVISUAL.ora into $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/
 Read VISUAL-trace.sql and modify as necessary. Should have information about paths to the dbfs (make the directories and put the files there, or modify VISUAL-trace.sql)

set your ORACLE_SID to VISUAL

sqlplus / as sysdba

startup nomount

@VISUAL-trace.sql

Should at least get you on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

Though i am not very good at oracle, but can help you. Just keep another copy of backup.

You need to run commands in cmd for import;

for DBF import, the syntax is: imp userid= DATAFILES=(df1, df2, ... df#)
So use this command : imp userid/password datafiles=(c:\oradata\'USERS01.DBF')

to import log file: imp userid/password log=c:DB\VISUAL.2010-07-22-1637.log

imp userid/password indexfile=c:DB\VISUAL-trace.sql

initVISUAL.ora seems to be an .ora file. You can just copy the TNS entry from that file and paste it to your TNS.ORA file,(Don't delete the previous entries)

Comment: Don't think so, the .DBF file are data files, not dump files, initVISUAL.ora is the init.ora and nothing to do with TNSNAMES.ORA. The log file looks like a bit of a red herring, and the ARC file may or may not be needed, but I'd hope not. The trace file will, if it's what I think it is, include database creation commands to recreate the database using the supplied data files, but will need editing and customisation. But I'd suggest this is fairly advanced stuff and not something a novice should be expected to attempt...

Comment: Although you can import a tablespace from a .DBF file, I don't think you can create a database from scratch that way; i.e. import the SYSTEM tablespace. For a start you don't have a userid/password yet.

Comment: Nothing in this answer makes sense!